# How to center align the keys from a custom keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to handle the inputType property of an EditText in 
 my custom keyboard.

Since I have to show just a few keys, I want to align them in center of the keyboard. Unfortunately the `<Row>` element don't have an `android:gravity` attribute.

I'm trying to create something similar:
[image: Screenshot]

I was thinking to add some other keys and keep them hidden so the space will be occupied but I don't think this is a good solution.

Do you know any way to center align the keys in a row?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to take buttons in Layout and then take the gravity of layout....
i m providing u a universal layout,which can be run on all layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
        ></RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:gravity="center"
            >

            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:gravity="center"
            >
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:gravity="center"
            >
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:gravity="center"
            >
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
            <Button 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="myTxt"
                />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

@Ungureanu Liviu, still any query,then plz ask.